# How I do transform the java file from mule 3.x to transform message component in mule 4.x

Tags: mulesoft

The following code is from mule 3.x java file.

```java
if (requestJson.has("addresses") && requestJson.getJSONObject("addresses").has("shipTo"))
    requestJson.getJSONObject("addresses").remove("shipTo");

if (requestJson.has("lines") && requestJson.getJSONArray("lines").length() > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < requestJson.getJSONArray("lines").length(); i++) {
        requestJson.getJSONArray("lines").getJSONObject(i).put("taxIncluded", "true");
```

Now, I am trying to migrate it to mule 4.x transform message component.
Can anyone suggest how to write this code using if and for loops in mule4 transform message component.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the input data is a JSON stored in the payload, the first snippet can be replaced by:

```
payload.address - "shipTo"
```

DataWeave is a functional language,. It doesn't hs a for loop. Instead you can map each element of the list:

```
payload.lines  map $ ++ {taxIncluded: "true"}
```

You might need to use the update operator for the last one if you want to keep other fields in the payload: https://blogs.mulesoft.com/news/anypoint-platform/update-fields-with-dataweave/

Note that your Java implementation will not interact with DataWeave.